# Nested Numba function performance

Tags: python, numba

currently I am trying to improve the performance of my python code. To do so I successfully use numba. In order to improve the structure of my code I create functions. Now I have noticed to my surprise that if I split the code into different numba functions, the code is significantly slower than if I put the whole code in one function with a numba decorator. 
An example would be:

```
@nb.njit
def fct_4(a, b):
    x = a ^ b
    setBits = 0
    while x > 0:
        setBits += x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return setBits


@nb.njit
def fct_3(c, set_1, set_2):
    h = 2
    if c not in set_1 and c not in set_2:
        if fct_4(0, c) <= h:
            set_1.add(c)
        else:
            set_2.add(c)


@nb.njit
def fct_2(c, set_1, set_2):
    fct_3(c, set_1, set_2)


@nb.njit
def fct_1(set_1, set_2):
    for x1 in range(1000):
        c = 2
        fct_2(c, set_1, set_2)
```

is slower than

```
@nb.njit
def fct_1(set_1, set_2):
    for x1 in range(1000):
        c = 2       
        h = 2
        if c not in set_1 and c not in set_2:
            if fct_4(0, c) <= h:
                set_1.add(c)
            else:
                set_2.add(c)
```

with

```
@nb.njit
def main_fct(set_1, set_2):
    for i in range(50):
        for x in range(1000):
            fct_1(set_1, set_2)

set_1 = {0}
set_2 = {47}

start = timeit.default_timer()
main_fct(set_1, set_2)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
```

(2.70 seconds vs 0.46 seconds). I thought this shouldn't make a difference. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: 1) You measure a mixture of runtime and compile time. Run the function once before timing to get the  runtime. 2) The LLVM backend decide whether to inline the function or call it, if the functions are not inlined a difference is expected. 3)Your functions are really complicated for a small example. Numba can't work on lists or dictionaries directly, they are converted to an internal representation which is very costly. Maybe this overhead isn't optimized away for nested functions, leading to poor performance.

Comment: Can I force the LLVM to incline functions? Would a signature be beneficial? Should I avoid using sets?

Answer (score 1):

Since python is a dynamically typed language, its function call overhead is quite high.

On top of that you are looping over the function calls, so the execution time incurred in calling the function and checking the arguments is multiplied 1000 times.

Comment: But all functions are initially compiled with numba. Therefore I assumed that there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Otherwise I guess I should just avoid to create too many separate functions..Or is there a way to improve performance by adding signatures?

Comment: Are you taking into account compilation time? In your case that could also play a part in additional time overhead. You can keep the arguments static Python 3.6 onwards but I don't think it will improve performance that much. However for your program I'd suggest you look at the big picture - why do you have multiple levels of looping, do you need to keeps things so modular etc, and make a decision